# How Can Display Receipt In Quotation in odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I using odoo 12 , I need display receipt similar point of sale receipt in quotation in sale module

Answer (score 0):

Just replicate the [Point of Sale Report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/point_of_sale/views/report_saledetails.xml) in the `sale.order` model. The `internal_layout` may be useful in that case

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_saledetails">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                <div class="page">

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2>Sales Details</h2>

                        <strong><t t-esc="date_start" t-options="{'widget': 'datetime'}"/> - <t t-esc="date_stop" t-options="{'widget': 'datetime'}"/></strong>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Orderlines -->
                    <h3>Products</h3>
                    <table  class="table table-sm">
                        <thead><tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price Unit</th>
                        </tr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr t-foreach='products' t-as='line'>
                            <t t-set="internal_reference" t-value="line['code'] and '[%s] ' % line['code'] or ''" />
                            <td><t t-esc="internal_reference" /><t t-esc="line['product_name']" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <t t-esc="line['quantity']" />
                                <t t-if='line["uom"] != "Unit(s)"'>
                                    <t t-esc='line["uom"]' /> 
                                </t>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <t t-esc='line["price_unit"]' />
                            <t t-if='line["discount"] != 0'>
                                Disc: <t t-esc='line["discount"]' />%
                            </t>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br/>

                    <h3>Payments</h3>
                    <table  class="table table-sm">
                        <thead><tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr t-foreach='payments' t-as='payment'>
                            <td><t t-esc="payment['name']" /></td>
                            <td><t t-esc="payment['total']" t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': currency_precision}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br/>

                    <h3>Taxes</h3>
                    <table  class="table table-sm">
                        <thead><tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Tax Amount</th>
                            <th>Base Amount</th>
                        </tr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr t-foreach='taxes' t-as='tax'>
                            <td><t t-esc="tax['name']" /></td>
                            <td><t t-esc="tax['tax_amount']" t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': currency_precision}"/></td>
                            <td><t t-esc="tax['base_amount']" t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': currency_precision}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <strong>Total: <t t-esc='total_paid' t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': currency_precision}"/></strong>

                </div>
            </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: This comment not the solution i need receipt create with java script similar point of sale recipt

Comment: @BeshoyWageh Please, write a more detailed question if you want an appropriate answer